# Condensation in refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator

I have a side-by-side refrigerator. Occasionally it is making louder noises than usual, almost like a clicking sound, which stops when either door is opened and resumes upon its closing. The side that is not the freezer has water and sometimes ice on the slot on the back, above the top shelf (attached photo). The unit otherwise seems to be working as expected. We are not opening the door frequently.

This all started about a week ago when my A/C stopped working during the two hottest days of the year, with temperatures above 90 degrees. Once the A/C was fixed, the noise seemed to be abating gradually, so I thought it was related, but neither it nor the condensation has totally gone away.

What is that slot for (the manual doesn't appear to identify it) and what may be going on? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, you live in Florida, or Huston

Comment: Nope, northeastern U.S.

Comment: It sounds like the Fan iced up and is stalled. You need to defrost the coil. There are several ways of doing it, turn it off, unload it then place a fan blowing into it for about 24 hours. You can also remove the covers etc and expose the coil and then either let a fan blow on it or gently warm it with a hair dryer on low. This is not a 5 minute process. When you are done clean the drain with hot water, I use a turkey baster with hot water in it.

Comment: @Not_Einstein well you do have lots of condensation on it

Comment: Check for proper door closure, e.g., that fridge is level (or even tilted *very slightly* back, so doors stay closed), that items in fridge are not caught in door, and that door seals are clean and intact. The hot, humid weather just made apparent already-existing air infiltration.

Comment: The humidity in your home is higher because the AC is not working so a little more moisture in the fridge is not out of line. It could be a chance that the noise started now, it could be a fan hitting ice and when the door is open the fan turns off, I have one that it was not a fan but the motor that opened a door between freezer and refrigerator I thought that one was going to be a fan same noise at the top center section covered by a plastic assembly that was a pain to get to.